# How can we avoid borders on input tags when they autocomplete

Tags: html, css

Lately I have been doing a form for a website I was working on but I realised the input tag was getting borders during autocompleter even when I specified border:none ... how can I fix this I tried a couple solutions using some css pseudo classes but nothing has worked since then ...

Comment: Please create an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please provide [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried yet?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are using Chrome. And the behavior you mentioned is seen on Autofill. If the assumptions are correct use the following to get the desired behavior:

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus{
border: none ! Important;
/* Some more desired behaviors */
}
```